# SQL Server SQL syntax - selecting rows between and ordering

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL

```
  SELECT * FROM ( 
   select id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row 
   from order where 
       (shopkeeper=116363) and (status > 0) and 
       (status <> 2) and 
       [creationdate] >= convert(datetime,'06/07/2013 00:00:01',103) and
       [creationdate] <= convert(datetime,'20/07/2013 23:59:59',103) ) a 
  WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 100
```

I want to add an "order by ID" to this query but when I add it to the end I get an error and when I add it after `<= convert(datetime,'20/07/2013 23:59:59',103)` I also get an error.

Where do I add this to the Query?
Thanks

Comment: What is the error you get, by looking at the query this should be working fine and adding order by at the end should give you results, did you check the quality of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    SELECT * FROM ( 
       select id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) as row 
       from order where 
         (shopkeeper=116363) and 
         (status > 0) and (status <> 2) and 
         [creationdate] >= convert(datetime,'06/07/2013 00:00:01',103) and 
         [creationdate] <= convert(datetime,'20/07/2013 23:59:59',103) ) a 
    WHERE row BETWEEN 1 AND 100 
    Order by a.Id
```